# Conditional checking in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

What’s the difference between:

```
!!(obj1 && obj2);
```

and

```
 (obj1 && obj2);
```

Comment: `console.log('a' && 'b', !!('a' && 'b'));` --- why didn't you try before ask? yeah, I know, it's boring, but it takes 10 seconds to check yourself. -1 for being lazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first will potentially return a string or an object, the second will return a boolean.

Because objects can be truthy in javascript, `A && B` will return the value of `B` if it is truthy, which may be an object.  But using !! will cast it to a boolean because the !B will convert it to true or false, and the second ! will move it to the correct boolean value

An example where the two will differ:

```
var a = "test", b ="example"
var ex1 = ((a && b)   === true)  // false
var ex2 = (!!(a && b) === true)  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is none.

In general, `!!` is used to cast to boolean without using a function call, similar to how `0^` can be used to cast to integer, `""+` can be used to cast to string, etc.

However, in this case, assuming it's inside an `if` statement, there's no difference at all since the `if` implicitly "casts" to a boolean to see if it's true or not.

Comment: "There is none." --- that's not true. You're making too much assumptions